# fetchEntityByKey not making any requests to the server

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to create a filemanager using Angularjs and I recently discovered Breezejs and was interested in trying to use it to communicate with my backend and manage my model relations. The backend is a rest api over which I have full control.

I am however running into a problem. I know the id of the file, so I would like to make a request to url of the form `backend_url/files/:fileId` where `:fileId` is the url of the file base64 encoded. According to the documentation I should use `EntityManager.fetchEntityByKey()` for this purpose. This is the function that i use to create the Angularjs service:

```
var FilestoreService = function () {

    var dataService, manager;

    dataService = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: "../VFS-Symfony-Backend/web/app_dev.php/filesystems/local/",

        hasServerMetadata: false
    });         

    manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService
    });

    manager.metadataStore.addEntityType(fileEntityType);

    return {
        findOneById: function (id) {
            /* I have tried to leave the 3th argument empty or changing it to false with the same results */
            return manager.fetchEntityByKey("File", id, true).then(function(){console.log("success");}).fail(function(){console.log("failure");});

            /* I have also tried the following approach with the same result:
            var type, key, query;

            type = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("File");
            key = new breeze.EntityKey(type, id);
            query = breeze.EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(key);

            return manager.executeQuery(query); 
             */
        }
    };
};
```

where `fileEntityType` is defined as:

```
var FileEntityType = new breeze.EntityType({
    shortName: "File"
});

FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "uri",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
    isNullable: false
}));
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "mTime",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.Int16,
    isNullable: false
}));
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "type",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
    isNullable: false
}));
 FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "size",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.int16,
    isNullable: true
}));
```

However, when I call `findOneById` no request is made to the server and 2 lines are logged to the console:

- `Should be empty:[]` by q.js
- `failure` (as per the `fail()` callback function)

A 'normal' query (`manager.executeQuery(new breeze.EntityQuery().from("Files"));`) does result in a request to the server as expected.

I am really quite lost here. I have searched for a solution all weekend and finaly decided to post on SO hoping someone might be able to help me.

Thanks very much for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ward suggested the EnityType I created did need one of its field to be marked as the key field. Besides that the EntityType also needs to have a `defaultResourceName` to be supplied to its constructor. I think this explains why the 'normal' query did work (the resourceName is supplied by `from()`) and why fetchEntityByKey did not work. The updated FileEntityType now looks like  this:

```
var FileEntityType = new breeze.EntityType({
    shortName: "File",
    defaultResourceName: "files"
});
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "id",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
    isNullable: false,
    isPartOfKey: true
}));

// These properties were not altered
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "uri",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
    isNullable: false
}));
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "mTime",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.Int16,
    isNullable: false
}));
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "type",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
    isNullable: false
}));
FileEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
    name: "size",
    dataType: breeze.DataType.int16,
    isNullable: true
}));
```

Comment: Glad you figured this out. If this item is closed, please click the checkmark to the left so we can track it as closed. Thanks for using Breeze.

Comment: I think you should have given Ward the credit for the fix. Not yourself.

Comment: I'm very grateful for Wards input and I agree he deserves all the credit he can get. I'm curious though how you would suggest I do this. I did refer to Ward at beginning of my answer and I did upvote his answer. Are you suggesting I should have accepted Wards answer even though that ended up not being the ideal solution for my case? Or should I add a more explicit line crediting Ward in this answer? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

At least one problem is that **you haven't identified the key ('id'?) in your metadata** description of the "File" entity type. You have defined *every other property except* the 'id' property.

> You know this but let me tell other readers of this question who may not understand that you are defining the metadata on the JS client rather than retrieving it from the server.

I'm also curious why you are using int16? Is that really the right type? Do you really need to shave off the two bytes?

Finally, Breeze's `fetchEntityByKey` won't make a request URL in the form "backend_url/files **/:fileId**". Instead, the request URL will be "backend_url/files **/?id=:fileId**" as befits an OData query. See the network traffic for Id queries in the queryTests.cs of the DocCode sample.

You can still get that file if the server expects the URL you specified. You won't be using the Breeze query syntax. You'll just hit the service with the URL it expects, e.g.,

```
function findOne(id) {
    // check cache first
    var file = manager.getEntityByKey('File', id);
    if (file) {
       console.log("got it from cache");
       return Q(file); // got it; return in resolved promise
    }
    // not in cache; get from server
    return breeze.EntityQuery
        .from('Files/'+id) // constructs the URL you want
        .using(manager).execute()
        .then(function(data){
            console.log("success");}
            // return the file in a resolved promise
            return data.results[0] || null; 
         })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log("failure: "+ error.message);
         });
}
```

This is a variation on the `getByIdCacheOrRemote` method in queryTest.cs in the DocCode sample.

Yes, it's longer. You're reimplementing `fetchEntityByKey` so you can hit the remote service the way it expects.

The method begins by looking for the file in cache. The `getEntityByKey` is a synchronous search of the cache. The `findOne` method has async syntax ... returns a promise ... because it *might* have to go to the server. So if we find the file in cache (synchronously), we wrap the result in a resolved Q.js promise for the benefit of the caller which is expecting `findOne` to be asynchronous.

If the file is not found in cache, you go to the server with a "query" that is **really just a request on the URL of your choice**.

I haven't tried this a long time. I'm sure you'll tell me if it works ... or does not. If it doesn't, it should and we'll fix it so it does.

Comment: Your solution to creating the url my backend expects does indeed work. However, since I have control over the backend API I decided to expand the backend to be compatible with odata requests as this feels like the proper solution. I had tried marking a property as part of the key earlier without any different results and removed this code as I asumed the key field might be autogenerated. I was not aware of the fact the fail callback would receive an error object and this helped me track down the problem: a `defaultResourceName` property needed to be supplied to the EnityType.